# Excel 2013 VBA Web Query connection string containing variable

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013, excel-web-query

I am getting a Run-time error'1004' error on the following line.

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.add(Connection:=connstring, Destination:=Range("$b$2"))
Destination:=Range("$b$1"))
```

The Variable connstring seems to be causing the problem. How do I properly use the variable name in this connection statement?

Help would be greatly appreciated

---

```
Sub add()

For x = 1 To 58000

 Worksheets("PAGES").Select
 Worksheets("PAGES").Activate

 connstring = "http://www.name-list.net/russia/1"

 With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.add(Connection:=connstring, Destination:=Range("$b$2"))
 Destination:=Range("$b$1"))

    .Name = "1"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .WebTables = "2"
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
    .WebDisableRedirections = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With

Next x
```

Comment: Consider using xmlhttp instead of webquery. This code downloads the data from 39 pages [**link**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20832017/import-tables-from-a-webpage-to-excel/20832886#20832886)

Answer (score 2):

Change connstring to be -->

```
connstring = "URL;http://www.name-list.net/russia/1"
```

Better still -->

```
Dim connstring As String
connstring = "URL;http://www.name-list.net/russia/1"
```

The MSDN doco for that method is [QueryTables.Add Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb178808%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

I can't guarantee the rest of your code will work as you expect. Why are you looping 58000 times?